# Notation for Kronecker product of a matrix and itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, operator-theory, products

What is the notation for the **Kronecker product** of a matrix and itself?

In other words, is there a short-hand way I can express the following:

1. $X⊗X$
2. $X⊗X⊗X$
3. $X⊗X⊗X⊗X$

Where $X$ is a matrix?

What I am looking for is analogous to the following when using the **multiplication** operator:

1. $x$ x $x$ = $x^2$
2. $x$ x $x$ x $x$ = $x^3$
3. $x$ x $x$ x $x$ x $x$ = $x^4$

> @IanColey suggests: $X^{⊗n}$

is this correct?

Comment: Could be $X^{\otimes\,n}$?

Comment: Is there any way I can check? Terribly sorry if I sound like a complete novice.. I do not have a formal mathematical background and often work with operators expressed in a programmatic way (e.g. via mathematica) but have no idea how to express it in a paper for journal publication.. Cheers @IanColey

Comment: $X^{\otimes n}$ is definitely an established notation for the $n$-th *tensor* product of $X$ with itself. The distinction between a Kronecker product and a tensor product is merely that of matrices vs. the linear maps that they represent -- a distinction mathematicians don't commonly reflect in their notation. So the notation should be safe to use for the $n$-fold Kronecker power.

Comment: Thank you @darijgrinberg, for clearing that up.